# Uploading File/s to Gridview rows as needed and display in the same Column after uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

I want to upload files into a Gridview and display the file name/s after the upload is completed.

Below is my aspx file that has generated the Gridview. How do I achieve File upload? Thank you in advance.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" SortExpression  ="Date"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Source" HeaderText="Source" SortExpression="Source" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message" SortExpression  ="Message"  />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
                    <asp:Button ID="saveBtn" runat="server"  CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>" CommandName="save"  Text="OK"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: do you want to save image path in database or not?

Comment: I wanted the file to be uploaded to a folder and then also show the file name in Gridview. And I actually wanted to upload multiple files too.

Answer (score 0):

[image: check it do you want just this?]

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

This code fulfills your requirement simply!

Comment: here i have selected a file and now it is uploaded to gridView and its name is displaying...

Comment: Thanks. However, I was looking to store that file for that row id after I fire the Button click: Below is my code for the button 

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="uploadFile" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server"  CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>" CommandName="save"  Text="OK" style=" color: #ff0000" OnClick="btnUpload_Click"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: ' protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files;

            foreach (var x in files) 
            {
                //loop through all files selected in file upload control!
   
            }

        }'

Comment: you simply need to add this code on btnClick event and get all your files in code behind!